# Adding the amounts at the end of a list of arrays in Python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a table of arrays each containing logs and the last index on each array has a dollar amount (0.01). I need to slice the array and loop through each array summing up the amounts to output a total.

I don't have the slightest clue how to do this.

When I print the logs this is what it outputs for reference.

```
@ 2014 2 14 00:03:01 Matt "login" 0.01
@ 2014 2 14 02:06:12 Mary "login" 0.01
@ 2014 2 14 07:12:05 Mary "cd ~/cs150/projects" 0.01
@ 2014 2 13 12:33:52 Boris "firefox&" 0.13
@ 2014 2 14 12:33:52 Boris "load http://yahoo.com" 0.01
@ 2014 2 15 03:42:27 Natasha "exit" 0.00
```

I was planning on looping through the table, slicing the array to retrieve the last piece, add it to a variable then print the total.

Thanks for any help, I'm new and have been stuck for awhile on this.

Comment: Why don't you follow your plan?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines are in a text file:

```
total=0.0
for line in open('filename'):
    total+=decimal(line.strip().split()[-1])

print total
```

Comment: `sum` is already a function. So you could just do `sum( [float(l.split()[-1]) for l in open('data.txt')] )`

Comment: Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you the dollar amount is expressed always as a static 3 digit float, then just continue with you plan using:

```
string.split()
```

to split the string with white space as a delimiter and/or:

```
dollars = float(string[-3:])
```

To get the float amount of dollars :)

Hope that helped!
Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is a list of lists as:

```
data = [['@', '2014', '2', '14', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01'],
['@', '2014', '2', '14', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01'],
['@', '2014', '2', '14', '07:12:05', 'Mary', '"cd ~/cs150/projects"', '0.01'],
['@', '2014', '2', '13', '12:33:52', 'Boris', '"firefox&"', '0.13'],
['@', '2014', '2', '14', '12:33:52', 'Boris', '"load http://yahoo.com"', '0.01'],
['@', '2014', '2', '15', '03:42:27', 'Natasha', '"exit"', '0.00']]
```

you can get the total as:

```
total = sum([Decimal(item[7]) for item in data])
```

If the data is in a file, you could read the file and construct `data` as above before calculating the `total`, which can be done as:

```
import csv
data = []
with open('datafile', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to use floats for money. Consider changing your answer to use `decimal`.